# How can we share ECR login step between the jobs

Tags: github-actions

I created 3 jobs, all are building the image and pushing into the ECR but as you can see I have to repeat the `Configure AWS Credentials` and `Log in to Amazon ECR` step.

Is there a way to reduce it?

```
jobs:
  build-app1:
    steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
    - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: reponame
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
  build-app2:
    steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
    - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: reponame2
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
  build-app3:
    steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
    - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: reponame3
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't as each job may represent a different machine. So basically once your job is finished machine is cleared and goes back to the pool and become available for a another workload.

Answer (score 1):

You can have matrix and run all three parallel. Below is the code snippet

```yaml
jobs:
  build-app:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  strategy:
      matrix:
        Repo: [Repo1, Repo2, Repo3]
    steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
    - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY:  ${{ matrix.Repo }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Or if you feel running three jobs on three different machines is not suitable for your needs then below shell script might help you

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ECR_IMAGE_NAME=<Image Name>
ECR_REPO_NAME=<ECR REPO 1>
ECR_IMAGE_URL=$ECR_REPO_NAME/$ECR_IMAGE_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

echo "Login in ECR"
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REPO_NAME
echo "logged in ECR"
docker build -t $ECR_IMAGE_NAME .
docker tag $ECR_IMAGE_NAME $ECR_IMAGE_URL
docker push $ECR_IMAGE_URL

echo "Logging out of $ECR_REPO_NAME"
docker logout
###########################################
ECR_IMAGE_NAME=<Image Name>
ECR_REPO_NAME=<ECR REPO 2>
ECR_IMAGE_URL=$ECR_REPO_NAME/$ECR_IMAGE_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

echo "Login in ECR"
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REPO_NAME
echo "logged in ECR"
docker build -t $ECR_IMAGE_NAME .
docker tag $ECR_IMAGE_NAME $ECR_IMAGE_URL
docker push $ECR_IMAGE_URL

echo "Logging out of $ECR_REPO_NAME"
docker logout
#########################################
ECR_IMAGE_NAME=<Image Name>
ECR_REPO_NAME=<ECR REPO 3>
ECR_IMAGE_URL=$ECR_REPO_NAME/$ECR_IMAGE_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

echo "Login in ECR"
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REPO_NAME
echo "logged in ECR"
docker build -t $ECR_IMAGE_NAME .
docker tag $ECR_IMAGE_NAME $ECR_IMAGE_URL
docker push $ECR_IMAGE_URL

echo "Logging out of $ECR_REPO_NAME"
docker logout
```

And run this script alone after the aws login step since all three repos are in same region,

```yaml
jobs:
  build-app:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1
    - name: Push Docker Images to ECR
      run: chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh
      env: 
       GITHUB_SHA: ${{github.sha}}
       AWS_REGION: us-east-1
```

Comment: There is an issue with using matrix. Like if I use
Repo: [Repo1, Repo2, Repo3] then there is another value that needs to be changed.
for example, if

repo1 then docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f dir1/dockerfile .

Similarly if
repo2 then docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f dir2/dockerfile .

How can I do that??

Comment: You can use the bash script and edit the values in that script and call the script from actions 

or

U can use ```if: ${{ matrix.Repo == Repo1 }}``` like conditions in your [actions.yaml](https://notepad.pw/5p71f22u)

Answer (score 0):

We have faced similar issues of long "copy-paste" YAML files in GitHub Actions.

This could have probably been easily avoided, if GitHub Actions supported YAML anchors (it seems like [they still don't](https://github.community/t/support-for-yaml-anchors/16128/71)).

Since this problem was unacceptable to me, I developed a configuration helper command line named [kojo](https://github.com/DannyBen/kojo) - which lets you create configuration templates.

With it, your configuration could look something like this:

```yaml
# workflow.yml
jobs:
  build-app1:
    @import build (repo: 'reponame1')
  build-app2:
    @import build (repo: 'reponame2')
  build-app3:
    @import build (repo: 'reponame3')
```

```yaml
# build.yml
steps:
# see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-region: us-east-1

# see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
- name: Log in to Amazon ECR
  id: login-ecr
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

- name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: %{repo}
    IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
  run: |
    docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
    docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Notice that I am passing a variable named `repo` from one file to another (`%{repo}` in `build.yml`).

Then, generating the final file is as easy as running:

```
$ kojo file workflow.yml --save out.yml
```

We have been using this approach with many production sites, for quite some time.

Full disclosure: I am the developer of `kojo` (open source), and only posting here since this problem was exactly the reason it was born (well - this and endless Kubernetes manifests...).